# Android project not compiling with Eclipse+ANT but works fine with ant command-line

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I'm working on that for more than one hour:

I have an android project, and because I am doing custom steps at compilation, I am using ANT to compile the project and generate the APK files.

1- if I use a "stupid" command line with ant:

```
ant init_debug
```

the android application is compiled and the apk file is created; it goes through my custom step (I have "echo" instructions displaying my custom steps and they are printed in the command line).

2- if I ask Eclipse to run my custom build file, it fails and Eclipse answers:

```
Buildfile: /home/[...]/custom_rules.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "clean" does not exist in the project "null". It is used from target "myrelease".

Total time: 95 milliseconds
```

And what's on line 24? the usual and common dependency declaration in <target>

```
<target name="init_debug" description="Initialize pre build and do DEBUG" depends="clean, debug">
```

a) I run "android update project -p ." several times

b) I closed and reopened Eclipse (worth trying! I've seen weird things solved like that in the past!)

c) My build.xml starts with <project> with my project name, so I tried "myproject.clean" instead of simply "clean" as dependency without success

d) I also tried "android_rules.clean" with the same result

e) my custom_build.xml also starts with <project>, though I did not put any name property.

I am running out of ideas, any help is welcome!

my full custom_rules.xml is as follow:

```
<!--?eclipse.ant.import ?-->
<project default="init_debug">
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  DEBUG & RELEASE  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <target name="init_release" description="Initialize pre build and do RELEASE">
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="/home/tomtom/dev/apache-ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <antcall target="myrelease">
            <param name="debugMode" value="false"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="init_debug" description="Initialize pre build and do DEBUG">
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="/home/tomtom/dev/apache-ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <antcall target="mydebug">
            <param name="debugMode" value="true"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="myrelease" description="Performs Clean + Compile RELEASE" depends="clean, release">
        <echo>--- RUNNING CUSTOM RELEASE ---</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="mydebug"  description="Performs  Clean + Compile DEBUG" depends="clean, debug">
        <echo>--- RUNNING CUSTOM DEBUG ---</echo>
    </target>

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  PRE- & POST-BUILD  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->

    <target name="-pre-build" depends="-strings_manipulations">
        <antcall target="-update_manifest_xml"/>
        <antcall target="-update_strings_xml"/>
        <antcall target="-update_bool_xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="-post-build">
        <!--antcall target="-restore_manifest_xml"/>
        <antcall target="-restore_strings_xml"/>
        <antcall target="-restore_bool_xml"/-->
        <antcall target="-echo_strings"/>
    </target>

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  UPDATE FILES  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <target name="-update_manifest_xml">
        <echo>--- RUNNING UPDATE_MANIFEST ---</echo>
        <antcall target="-manifest_manipulation">
            <param name="manifest_path" value=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="-update_strings_xml">
        <echo>--- RUNNING UPDATE_STRINGS ---</echo>
        <copy
            file="res/values/strings.xml"
            tofile=".strings.xml.antbak"
            preservelastmodified="true"
        />
        <property   name="v.start.string"   value='&#60;string name="app_version"&#62;'                     />
        <property   name="end.string"       value="&#60;/string&#62;"                                       />
        <replaceregexp
            file="res/values/strings.xml"
            match="${v.start.string}.*${end.string}"
            replace="${v.start.string}${version.string}${end.string}"
        />
        <property   name="c.start"  value='&#60;string name="app_linesofcode"&#62;' />
        <replaceregexp
            file="res/values/strings.xml"
            match="${c.start}.*${end.string}"
            replace="${c.start}${linesOfCode}${end.string}"
        />
    </target>

    <target name="-update_bool_xml">
        <echo>--- RUNNING UPDATE_BOOLEAN (${debugMode}) ---</echo>
        <copy
            file="res/values/bool.xml"
            tofile=".bool.xml.antbak"
            preservelastmodified="true"
        />
        <property   name="start.bool"   value='&#60;bool name="DEBUG_MODE"&#62;'/>
        <property   name="end.bool"     value="&#60;/bool&#62;"/>
        <replaceregexp
            file="res/values/bool.xml"
            match="${start.bool}.*${end.bool}"
            replace="${start.bool}${debugMode}${end.bool}"
        />
    </target>

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  RESTORE FILES  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <target name="-restore_manifest_xml">
        <echo>Restoring backup of AndroidManifest.xml</echo>
        <move
            file=".AndroidManifest.xml.antbak"
            tofile="AndroidManifest.xml"
            preservelastmodified="true"
            overwrite="true"
        />
    </target>

    <target name="-restore_strings_xml">
        <echo>Restoring backup of strings.xml</echo>
        <move
            file=".strings.xml.antbak"
            tofile="res/values/strings.xml"
            preservelastmodified="true"
            overwrite="true"
        />
    </target>

    <target name="-restore_bool_xml">
        <echo>Restoring backup of bool.xml</echo>
        <move
            file=".bool.xml.antbak"
            tofile="res/values/bool.xml"
            preservelastmodified="true"
            overwrite="true"
        />
    </target>

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  STRING MANIPULATIONS  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <target name="-strings_manipulations">
        <exec executable="cloc" output="code">
            <arg value="${basedir}"></arg>
        </exec>
        <loadfile srcFile="code" property="linesOfCode">
            <filterchain>
                <containsregex pattern="^SUM:.*[0-9]*$" />
            </filterchain>
        </loadfile>
        <propertyregex
            property="linesOfCode"
            override="true"
            input="${linesOfCode}"
            regexp="SUM:\s*\d*\s*\d*\s*\d*\s*(\d*)"
            select="\1"
        />
        <buildnumber file="build.num"/>
        <property   name="version.AppCode"  value="2"/>
        <property   name="version.number"   value="1"/>
        <property   name="version.revision" value="0"/>
        <property   name="version.string"   value="${version.AppCode}.${version.number}.${version.revision}.${build.number}"    />
    </target>

    <target name="-manifest_manipulation">
        <property   name="start.manifest.name"  value='android:versionName="'       />
        <property   name="end.manifest.name"    value='"&#62;'                      />
        <echo>Manifest Path: ${manifest_path}AndroidManifest.xml</echo>
        <copy
            file="${manifest_path}AndroidManifest.xml"
            tofile="${manifest_path}.AndroidManifest.xml.antbak"
            preservelastmodified="true"
        />
        <replaceregexp
            file="${manifest_path}AndroidManifest.xml"
            match="${start.manifest.name}.*${end.manifest.name}"
            replace="${start.manifest.name}${version.string}${end.manifest.name}"
        />
        <property   name="start.manifest.code"  value='android:versionCode="'       />
        <property   name="end.manifest.code"    value='"'                           />
        <replaceregexp
            file="${manifest_path}AndroidManifest.xml"
            match="${start.manifest.code}.*${end.manifest.code}"
            replace="${start.manifest.code}${version.AppCode}${end.manifest.code}"
        />
    </target>
    <target name="-echo_strings">
        <echo>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</echo>
        <echo>++</echo>
        <echo>++ Lines of Code: ${linesOfCode}</echo>
        <echo>++</echo>
        <echo>++ Version Code : ${version.string}</echo>
        <echo>++</echo>
        <echo>++ DEBUG MODE : ${debugMode}</echo>
        <echo>++</echo>
        <echo>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance! 
Tom.

Comment: How about trying out googles current tooling? http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: lol! Sure! It looks more like a work around than a solution, but of course it could solve my compile issue... Still, I have 4 or 5 other projects based on the exact same scheme, and they work pretty well. I compared the custom_build.xml and build.xml files, they look the same. Problem must be somewhere in ant imports or something like that, but I cannot figure out what's wrong. thx anyway! :)